# A (possibly) new way of arriving at the Newton-Raphson method??

Tags: calculus, functions, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

I'd really like some opinions on this. I feel my reasoning in the later steps is quite weak. The results tell me I guess that alpha = beta at the stat point, and that the approximation becomes exact in this limit (obvious). What intrigues me, though, are the forms taken by rho at the stat point (rho star) ie the similarity with NR

URL to paper: http://www.academia.edu/26637694/On_a_Simple_Geometric_Interpretation_of_the_Newton-Raphson_Method

Thanks

Comment: You must signup to get the document. This is not acceptable.

Comment: No you don't, scroll down.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: I am completely lost regarding the geometric interpretation of $\rho^*$.

Comment: I guess an included plot would be useful. What I'm saying is that as our guesses approach the root, so does ρ. I go on to say, then, that the best approximation is given at a stationary point (ρ ∗) - the point at which this approach stops.

Comment: It would be so much more helpful if people had something to say rather than just disliking. I'm just asking for some help!! (not directed at you, Yves)

Comment: I don't see a geometric interpretation in what you say. What's the connection to the initial figure ?

Comment: The geometric interpretation is supposed to be the first figure in that it leads to the final result. The function rho becomes a better approximation as alpha and beta approach r. I try to find, from this function, a best approximation. I noticed (before learning partial differentiation) that rho approaches the root when I varied alpha, and kept beta const (and vice versa) - the approach was towards a stationary point. I've replicated that, but in 3D.

Comment: So I still don't see any geometric interpretation of Newton. Also pretty perturbing to work with a two-points method to derive a one-point method.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting with an interval and evaluating the function and its derivatives at the end points. This should lead you to the Interval Arithmetic and function enclosures. A Newton method for finding (enclosing) all (!) the roots in a given interval is called [Interval Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Interval_Newton_method). See Warwick Tucker's
*Validated Numerics: A Short Introduction to Rigorous Computations*, 2011.